# XPath select nodes multiple times dependent on attributes for XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a node like this one:

```
<foo my:first="yes" my:second="no">text</foo>
```

I need an XPath query or XSLT function which selects each node with attributes in the "my" namespace. But if an element has multiple "my" attributes, the element needs to be selected multiple times.

Currently I have this:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@my:*]">
  <bar>
    <xsl:variable name="attributeName" select="local-name(./@my:*)" />
    <xsl:variable name="attributeValue" select="./@my:*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="$attributeName" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="$attributeValue" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <bar>
</xsl:template>
```

And naturally, it only supports single "my" attributes, which results in a transformation like this:

```
<bar name="attr_in_my_namespace" value="value_of_that_attr">text</bar>
```

If I try this with the node I presented in the beginning, I get the following error:

```
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
  local-name() (@my:first, @my:second)
```

So, the expected result would be:

```
<bar name="first" value="yes">text</bar>
<bar name="second" value="no">text</bar>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if you simply want to process the attribute nodes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*/@my:*">
  <bar name="{local-name()}" value="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="*[@my:*]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@my:*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You may be just right! Thanks for your help, i'll try it out.

Comment: How can i select the node's inner text in the attribute template? I need to put the contents of the element in between the `bar`tags.

Comment: I edited the first template as in my first answer attempt I overlooked you want to output the element content as well.